# Postgres: Autovacuum and autovacuum wraparound. When does each start?

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I've got 'autovacuum_freeze_max_age' which is 200 000 000 by default.
And in theory I found a rule that autovacuum wraparound starts when:

```
If age(relfrozenxid) > autovacuum_freeze_max_age
```

But when then usual autovacuum is started? How can I count a moment:

1. When usual autovacuum on a table is started?
2. When autovacuum becomes autovacuum wraparound? Really after age(relfrozenxid) > autovacuum_freeze_max_age?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) states, normal autovacuum is triggered

> if the number of tuples obsoleted since the last `VACUUM` exceeds the “vacuum threshold”, the table is vacuumed. The vacuum threshold is defined as:
>
> ```
> vacuum threshold = vacuum base threshold + vacuum scale factor * number of tuples
> ```
>
> where the vacuum base threshold is [autovacuum_vacuum_threshold](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-THRESHOLD), the vacuum scale factor is [autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-SCALE-FACTOR), and the number of tuples is `pg_class.reltuples`.
>
> The table is also vacuumed if the number of tuples inserted since the last vacuum has exceeded the defined insert threshold, which is defined as:
>
> ```
> vacuum insert threshold = vacuum base insert threshold + vacuum insert scale factor * number of tuples
> ```
>
> where the vacuum insert base threshold is [autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-INSERT-THRESHOLD), and vacuum insert scale factor is [autovacuum_vacuum_insert_scale_factor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-SCALE-FACTOR).

The second part applies only to PostgreSQL v13 and later.

Furthermore,

> If the `relfrozenxid` value of the table is more than `vacuum_freeze_table_age` transactions old, an aggressive vacuum is performed to freeze old tuples and advance `relfrozenxid`; otherwise, only pages that have been modified since the last vacuum are scanned.

So an autovacuum worker run that was triggered by the normal mechanism can run as an anti-wraparound `VACUUM` if there are old enough rows in the table.

Finally,

> Tables whose `relfrozenxid` value is more than `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` transactions old are always vacuumed

So if a table with old live tuples is never autovacuumed during normal processing, a special anti-wraparound autovacuum run is triggered for it, even if autovacuum is disabled. Such an autovacuum run is also forced if there are multixacts that are older than [`vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-VACUUM-MULTIXACT-FREEZE-TABLE-AGE), see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-MULTIXACT-WRAPAROUND). From PostgreSQL v14 on, if an unfrozen row in a table is older than [`vacuum_failsafe_age`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-VACUUM-FAILSAFE-AGE), an anti-wraparound autovacuum will skip index cleanup for faster processing.

Yes, this is pretty complicated.

Comment: Haven't found a ready query, which compute these vacuum situations. MAybe you've got?

Comment: What query? If that is about monitoring, you could have one query to watch out for excessively many dead tuples and one for databases/tables approaching wraparound.

Comment: Little remark.  vacuum insert threshold is also from 13 Postgres.

Comment: I know, I added that. I also said that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Made a query which shows the dead turple (when simple vacuum is started) and when vacuum wrapadaround:

```
 with dead_tup as ( 
 SELECT st.schemaname || '.' || st.relname tablename,
         st.n_dead_tup dead_tup,
         current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_threshold')::int8 +
         current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor')::float * c.reltuples
         max_dead_tup,
         (current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_threshold')::int8 +
         current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor')::float * c.reltuples - st.n_dead_tup) as left_for_tr_vacuum,
         st.last_autovacuum,
         c.relnamespace,
         c.oid
  FROM   pg_stat_all_tables st,
         pg_class c
  WHERE  c.oid = st.relid
  AND    c.relkind IN ('r','m','t')
  AND    st.schemaname not like ('pg_temp%'))
SELECT  c.oid::regclass as table,
        current_setting('autovacuum_freeze_max_age')::int8 -
        age(c.relfrozenxid) as xid_left,
        pg_relation_size(c.oid) as relsize, 
        dt.dead_tup,
        dt.max_dead_tup,
        dt.left_for_tr_vacuum,
        dt.last_autovacuum 
from (pg_class c 
      join pg_namespace n on (c.relnamespace=n.oid)
      left join dead_tup dt on (c.relnamespace=dt.relnamespace and c.oid=dt.oid))
where c.relkind IN ('r','m','t') --and (age(c.relfrozenxid)::int8 > (current_setting('autovacuum_freeze_max_age')::int8 * 0.8))
      AND n.nspname not like ('pg_temp%')
order by 2
```